# Gnuplot logarithmic color scale

Tags: gnuplot

I've been making 2D plots of patterns using GNUPLOT, but, I need the color to be in a logarithmic scale, but only the color, not the numeric values and their corresponding tics in the color column. Is there a way to do that?

Here I have an example of one [data file](https://github.com/ykmo-v/pro1/blob/main/Sq.dat) for generating the image.
In GNUPLOT I use the following commands (or script):

```
set size square 1,1
set cbrange [0:2]
set pm3d map
set palette defined ( 0 'gray30', 0.75 'gray20', 1.35 'cyan')
splot 'Sq.dat' with pm3d
```

[image: Example of a image that is created]

Comment: Your data ranges from 0 (and 6.5e-6 as smallest value>0) to 144. How exactly do you want to map this range to color? Should 6.5e-6 correspond to 'gray30' and 144 to 'cyan' with a logarithmic transition? What about the darker 'gray20'  in between? Where do the values 0, 0.75 and 1.35 in your defined palette come from?

Comment: That was just an example, not a real attempt with a logarithmic scale. I would want a logarithmic 'gradient' with just one color, if that is possible. I assumed that, if it is possible, black will be at the lowest values and 'full' cyan will be at the highests. The values 0, 0.75 and 1.35 refer to the range [0,2] in this example, they are a random choice of values to try and build a gradient with three colors that maintain the details at the lowest values.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `set logscale cb`? If you have a certain color in the graph you want to look it up in the color bar which of course then has logarithmic tics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the gnuplot console check `help palette` and `help palette functions`.
There is the option `functions`. For each of the color components (R,G,B) you define a function which has the variable `gray` as input (range `[0:1]`) and should have a range `[0:1]` as output. If you type `test palette` you can check the palette output.

If all your functions for R,G,B start from `0` this will be black. If the functions for G and B end at `1` and R stays at `0`, this will by cyan.

There are also 37 predefined functions when using the option `set palette rgbformulae`: check `help palette rgbformulae` and `show palette rgbformulae`.

**Examples:**

```
# Linear:
set palette functions  0, gray, gray
test palette
```

[image]

```
# Square:
set palette functions  0, gray**2, gray**2
test palette
```

[image]

```
# Square Root:
set palette functions  0, sqrt(gray), sqrt(gray)
test palette
```

[image]

```
# Some logarithm: (play with x0)
f(x,x0) = log((x+x0)/x0)/log((1+x0)/x0)
x0 = 0.01
set palette functions  0, f(gray,x0), f(gray,x0)
test palette
```

[image]

**Addition:** (your data with `logscale cb`)

**Script:**

```
### logscale cb
reset session

FILE = "SO76096868.dat"

set size ratio -1
set palette functions 0, gray**2, gray**2
# set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10     #  alternatively, multiple colors

set view map
set logscale cb
set format cb "10^{%T}"
set xrange [:] noextend
set yrange [:] noextend

splot FILE u 1:2:3 w pm3d
### end of script
```

**Results:**

[image]

[image]